# How to achieve a "shiny" effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

[image: An example of the shiny effect]

I'm trying to obtain this kind of effect in Photoshop but can't get it exactly.  Things I have tried:

- First I made a oval shape with white color;
- Then I gave it a Gaussian blur effect;
- Then I made that layer soft light.

But I couldn't replicate the effect. Can anyone help with this? Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you had a screenshot of your attempt, but I think I can guess where you are having an issue. Try making the color of the glow a similar color to the object that's glowing. In your example, notice that the outer edges of the glow are a pink color, not white.

If I were making the effect, I would have two layers (as you did) and set the top layer's blending mode to "Overlay". Try setting both layers to Overlay and see if you like the effect.

Comment: `Color Dodge` can work too, you just need to take the opacity down a little bit.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know, you just make multiple layers and get closer step by step, I needed just a few minutes for this. Take a good look at what the effect is and try to think of what it is composed of. Color, shapes, gradients.. 
[image]

Comment: Well, please add a way to recreate the effect you showed in your image.  The op needs to learn how to do that ...